# Adjustable pagewidth problems, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem trying to adjust my HTML body and footer with a width that's as wide as the user's screen. On many sites they say `document.body.clientWidth` is the users screenwidth minus toolbars, etc. But this apears to be wrong because i have a screenwidth of 1024 and as you can see below i made a test environment wich indicates that the usable screenwidth is 1366 so my website is far to wide..

Many thanks

HTML :

```
<body id="body" onload="init();">
    <p id="screenwidth">0</p>
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="ruimte"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

functies.js :

```
function init(){  
    document.body.style.width = document.body.clientWidth + "px";
    document.getElementById("footer").style.width = document.body.clientWidth + "px";
    document.getElementById("screenwidth").innerHTML = document.body.clientWidth;  
}
```

Comment: The Web-Stoneage is over, so it would be much better to **use CSS** for this kind of task. For full-width you could just use `width: 100%;`. You can also combine `margins` and `paddings` or even use `position: absolute;` to achieve position and size your elements. Also, think about the people with **deactivated JavaScript** - they want beautiful layouts, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used your exact code and `document.body.clientWidth` worked fine for me (gave the correct width 1024) in a bunch of different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Could you tell me why you need js to set the width of the body/footer?
Their widths should already be the one of the window.

Comment: it's just a testpage for something else i'm trying. The only question i actually ask is: Why doesn't document.body.clientWidth give the right width?

Comment: Ok... So I don't really know why the result is wrong. I guess it depends on your browser. http://www.geekpedia.com/code100_Get-window-width-and-height.html . Or you can use jQuery and do $(window).width(). The result should then be consistent across browsers.

Comment: your link doesn't help a lot but thanks for everything. Everyone is talking about JQuery i should check it out some time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get the inner width of your page

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
```

this will subtract the scrollbar too.